# how make Route Model Binding run with any route that I need?

Tags: laravel

I have this route:

```
Route::resource('newusers', 'NewUsersController');
```

I need to use **Route Model Binding**  in `Controller`.

```
public function destroy(User $user)
{
    $user->delete();
    session()->flash('success', 'Delete User Successfuly');
    return redirect(adminUrl('newusers'));
}
```

And why Route Model Binding does not work with any Controller ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The argument name has to match the route parameter for Implicit Route Model Binding to take place:

```
public function destroy(User $newuser)
```

The `Route::resource` call will create route parameters in the singular form of the resource:

```
Route::resource('newusers', 'NewUsersController');

// newusers/{newuser}
```

> "Laravel automatically resolves Eloquent models defined in routes or controller actions whose type-hinted variable names **match** a route segment name."

I just answered a similar question earlier:

[Laravel 6: named routes inside a folder doesn't get the user object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59392016/laravel-6-named-routes-inside-a-folder-doesnt-get-the-user-object/59392054#59392054)